# PreferenceActivity has missing icon on Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've created a simple PreferenceActivity containing a ListActivity. (code added at the end for completeness) but it shows up differently on a 2.3 device and on a Galaxy Tab 10.1" (Android 3.2) (see images below).

My questions are:

- Can I also get the icon with the right arrow in Honeycomb?
- Can I avoid the empty black line between the title of the activity and the ListPreference

[image: Android 2.3 screenshot][image: Android 3.2 screenshot]

```
public class TestPreference extends PreferenceActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());  
}

private PreferenceScreen createPreferenceHierarchy() 
{
    // Root
    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    /*
     * select language
     */
    ListPreference listPref = new ListPreference(this);     
    listPref.setKey("Language");
    listPref.setEntries(new String[]{"eng", "fra"});
    listPref.setEntryValues(new String[]{"eng", "fra"});
    listPref.setValue("eng");//TODO: assumes English is a supported language!?
    listPref.setSummary("You can select your language here");
    listPref.setTitle("Select Language");
    root.addPreference(listPref);


    return root;
}
}
```